# The ability to compile a rust program using python

Tags: python, rust, compilation

I would like to call the compilation of a rust program from a python script. Are there any options to pull this off?

```
def compile():
    binary_file = rust_compile(path, release=True)
    return binary_file
```

Comment: What would you expect to do after compiling this program? Don't you want to compile a shared library and call it from Python?

Comment: just call `cargo build` from a shell process to compile the rust program, passing in any relevant flags such as release, and set `cwd` to current dir to execute the command from. though, i'm not sure if that is all you are expecting to be able to do from py code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library `subprocess` to execute console commands and doing so execute the rust compiler.

`subprocess.run(["rustc","program.rc"])`

And then get the path of the binary file